# Probability of the existence of a specific pattern in one million coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I came across this question while preparing for an interview.

Given a coin with head-up probability p, flip it $N = 1,000,000$ times. What is the probability that a string of "HHHHHHTTTTTT" (i.e. 6 heads followed by 6 tails) exists? Can this pattern be generalized?

Any idea on the question? Thanks in advance!

This question has two related questions:

1. Average number of the pattern.
2. Average number of the pattern of at least 6 tails in a row.

For Question 1, one can solve it using the linearity of expectation. Specifically, let $X_i$ be a binary variable indicating whether there is one such pattern starting at the ith flip. Then the average number of the pattern across all one million flips is just
\begin{align*}
E \sum_{i=1}^{N-11} X_i &= \sum_{i=1}^{N-11} E X_i \\
&= (N-11) p^6(1-p)^6.
\end{align*}

Question 2 can be solved in a similar way. The only difference is that this time $X_i=1$ requires that the $(i-1)$th flip is a head. Hence
\begin{align*}
E \sum_{i=1}^{N-5} X_i &= E X_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{N-5} E X_i \\
&= (1-p)^6+(N-6) p(1-p)^6 \\
&=(1+Np-6p)(1-p)^6.
\end{align*}

Comment: The probability question is surprisingly delicate. It can be computed using something called the autocorrelation polynomial of a string; you can try looking up that keyword.

Comment: Question 2 may needs a minor adjustment as I suspect you should be multiplying by $(N-6)$ as HTTTTTT is of length $7$ and perhaps for TTTTTT initially perhaps you should add $(1-p)^6$. So possibly $(Np-6p+1)(1-p)^6$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing out this issue; edited to fix it.

Comment: Consider a simplified version of the problem: What is the probability that a string of "HH" exist? There a $2^N$ possible strings. Let $G_N$ be the number of strings that don't have the pattern "HH". If the first toss is $T$ then the rest of the strings can be any combinations that do not have $HH$, that is $G_{N-1}$. If the first toss is $H$, then the second must be $T$ and the rest of the strings can be any combinations that do not have $HH$, that is $G_{N-2}$. So $G_N = G_{N-1} + G_{N-2}$. The answer to the simplified problem is $1-G_N/2^N$. Maybe you can solve the problem along these lines